# django get all childs with given parent_id

Tags: django

I have to populate a select field based on another select field's selection. The first select is the school and the second select should be the classes in that school. I use an ajax call and in my view I have following code but without results:

```
def get_classes_by_school_id(request):
    school_id = request.POST.get('school_id', None)

    data = {
    'listClasses': Classes.objects.filter(school=school_id).values('id', 'title', 'abbr')
    }

    return JsonResponse({'data': list(data)})
```

console.log($.parseJSON(data)); returns

```
{data: ["listClasses"]}
    data:["listClasses"]
        0:"listClasses"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` variable is a `dict`, but you did `list(data)` later on. `list(data)` basically converts a dict into a list, only taking the keys. In your `data` data structure, the only key is `listClasses`, that's why you got `[listClasses]` in the end.

An example:

```
>>> list({1:2, 3:4})
[1, 3]
```

You might need:

```
return JsonResponse({'data': list(data['listClasses'])})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = list({"key1" : value1 , "key2" : value2 })
    ["key1" , "key2"]
```

**Try this**

```
def get_classes_by_school_id(request):
        school_id = request.POST.get('school_id', None)

        data = {
        'data': Classes.objects.filter(school=school_id).values('id', 'title', 'abbr')
        }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

And in **javascript**

```
var = JSON.parse(response)
var list = response["data"]
```

Answer (score 1):

here the way I solved it finaly :

```
def get_classes_by_school_id(request):
    school_id = request.POST.get('school_id', None)

    school = get_object_or_404(School, pk=school_id)
    queryset = Classes.objects.filter(school=school).values('id', 'abbr')
    data = [{'id': item['id'], 'abbr': item['abbr']} for item in queryset]

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

and in my javascript:

```
var options = '';
$.each(data, function (key, element) {
    options += '<option value="' + element.id + '">' + element.abbr + '</option>';
});
```

I couldn't get your responses working, but thx anyway...